# Default conditions for Rails models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, named-scope

I have a model which has a field called `deleted`, which is used to mark those deleted items.

So normally I would just want to query those having `deleted = false` items, and in some special cases to list those deleted items for restoring.

Is it possible to do that? What I could do now is just using a named scope having `:conditions => {:deleted => false}`

Is there a better way to do it so that When I do `Item.other_named_scope`, I could find all those not-deleted items?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use default_scope for this.

```
class Post
  default_scope :conditions => {:deleted => false}
end
```

Now all queries to the `Post` model will be on `ACTIVE` posts. When you want to override this behavior use `with_exclusive_scope`:

```
Post.with_exclusive_scope{ find_all_by_deleted(true) } #returns deleted records
```

**Reference:**

[Link 1](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/11/18/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-default-scoping)

**Caveat**

The default_scope affects every finder call. It should be used with care and with full awareness of the unwanted side-effects.

Comment: Despite the caveats I still recommend avoiding conditions with default scope and using it more for `order by`.  It's likely that someone else (or the future you) will forget about the query limiting part and will be scratching their head for a while chasing phantom bugs due to it.  My 2 cents from experience :)

Comment: @MichaelDurrant, I avoid default scopes in most scenarios for the reason you have stated. That being said, I revisit the issue whenever I have to make a call on choosing an approach for excluding the `deleted` records. Few times I have tentatively chosen the default scope approach.